# How to implement a soft-margin SVM model using Matlab's quadprog?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, quadprog

Suppose we are given a training dataset `{yᵢ, xᵢ}`, for `i = 1, ..., n`, where `yᵢ` can either be `-1` or `1` and `xᵢ` can be e.g. a 2D or 3D point.

In general, when the input points are *linearly separable*, the SVM model can be defined as follows

```
min 1/2*||w||²
w,b
```

subject to the constraints (for `i = 1, ..., n`)

```
yᵢ*(w*xᵢ - b) >= 1
```

This is often called the [**hard-margin** SVM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Hard-margin), which is thus a [constrained minimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization), where the unknowns are `w` and `b`. We can also omit `1/2` in the function to be minimized, given it's just a constant.

Now, the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) about Matlab's `quadprog` states

> `x = quadprog(H, f, A, b)` minimizes `1/2*x'*H*x + f'*x` subject to the restrictions `A*x ≤ b`. `A` is a matrix of doubles, and `b` is a vector of doubles.

We can implement the hard-margin SVM model using `quadprog` function, to get the weight vector `w`, as follows

- `H` becomes an identity matrix.
- `f'` becomes a zeros matrix.
- `A` is the left-hand side of the constraints
- `b` is equal to `-1` because the original constraint had `>= 1`, it becomes `<= -1` when we multiply with `-1` on both sides.

---

Now, I am trying to implement a [**soft-margin** SVM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Soft-margin). The minimization equation here is

```
min (1/2)*||w||² + C*(∑ ζᵢ)
w,b
```

subject to the constraints (for `i = 1, ..., n`)

```
yᵢ*(w*xᵢ - b) >= 1 - ζᵢ
```

such that `ζᵢ >= 0`, where `∑` is the summation symbol, `ζᵢ = max(0, 1 - yᵢ*(w*xᵢ - b))` and `C` is a [hyper-parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_(machine_learning)).

How can this optimization problem be solved using the Matlab's `quadprog` function? It's not clear to me how the equation should be mapped to the parameters of the `quadprog` function.

The "**primal**" form of the soft-margin SVM model (i.e. the definition above) can be converted to a "[**dual**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Dual)" form. I did that, and I am able to get the Lagrange variable values (in the dual form). However, I would like to know if I can use `quadprog` to solve directly the primal form without needing to convert it to the dual form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see how it can be a problem. Let `z` be our vector of `(2n + 1)` variables:

```
z = (w, eps, b)
```

Then, `H` becomes diagonal matrix with first `n` values on the diagonal equal to `1` and the last `n + 1` set to zero:

```
H = diag([ones(1, n), zeros(1, n + 1)])
```

Vector `f` can be expressed as:

```
f = [zeros(1, n), C * ones(1, n), 0]'
```

First set of constrains becomes:

```
Aineq = [A1, eye(n), zeros(n, 1)]
bineq = ones(n, 1)
```

where `A1` is a the same matrix as in primal form.

Second set of constraints becomes lower bounds:

```
lb = (inf(n, 1), zeros(n, 1), inf(n, 1))
```

Then you can call MATLAB:

```
z = quadprog(H, f, Aineq, bineq, [], [], lb);
```

P.S. I can be mistaken in some small details, but the general idea is right.

Comment: The way the "n" variable was thrown around confused me even more but I got the general idea. The n variable doesn't match up well in quite a few places. 

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1067334 Does n represent number of features or number of training samples?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to clarify [@vharavy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015239/vharavy) answer because you could get lost while trying to deduce what 'n' means in his code. Here is my version according to his answer and SVM wikipedia article. I assume we have a file named *"test.dat"* which holds coordinates of test points and their class membership in the last column.
Example content of *"test.dat"* with 3D points:

```
-3,-3,-2,-1
-1,3,2,1
5,4,1,1
1,1,1,1
-2,5,4,1
6,0,1,1
-5,-5,-3,-1
0,-6,1,-1
-7,-2,-2,-1
```

Here is the code:

```
data = readtable("test.dat");
tableSize = size(data);
numOfPoints = tableSize(1);
dimension = tableSize(2) - 1;
PointsCoords = data(:, 1:dimension);
PointsSide = data.(dimension+1);

C = 0.5; %can be changed
n = dimension;
m = numOfPoints; %can be also interpretet as number of constraints
%z = [w, eps, b]; number of variables in 'z' is equal to n + m + 1
H = diag([ones(1, n), zeros(1, m + 1)]);
f = [zeros(1, n), C * ones(1, m), 0];
Aineq = [-diag(PointsSide)*table2array(PointsCoords), -eye(m), PointsSide];
bineq = -ones(m, 1);
lb = [-inf(1, n), zeros(1, m), -inf];
z = quadprog(H, f, Aineq, bineq, [], [], lb);
```

Answer (score -1):

If let z = (w; w0; eps)T be a the long vector with n+1+m elements.(m the number of points)
Then,

```
H= diag([ones(1,n),zeros(1,m+1)]).
f = [zeros(1; n + 1); ones(1;m)]
```

The inequality constraints can be specified as :

```
A = -diag(y)[X; ones(m; 1); zeroes(m;m)] -[zeros(m,n+1),eye(m)],
```

where X is the n x m input matrix in the primal form.Out of the 2 parts for A, the first part is for w0 and the second part is for eps.

```
b = ones(m,1)
```

The equality constraints :

```
Aeq = zeros(1,n+1 +m)
beq = 0
```

Bounds:

```
lb = [-inf*ones(n+1,1); zeros(m,1)]
ub = [inf*ones(n+1+m,1)]
```

Now, `z=quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)`

Answer (score -1):

Complete code. The idea is the same as above.

```
n = size(X,1);
m = size(X,2);
H = diag([ones(1, m), zeros(1, n + 1)]);
f = [zeros(1,m+1) c*ones(1,n)]';
p = diag(Y) * X;
A = -[p Y eye(n)];
B = -ones(n,1);
lb = [-inf * ones(m+1,1) ;zeros(n,1)];
z = quadprog(H,f,A,B,[],[],lb);
w = z(1:m,:);
b = z(m+1:m+1,:);
eps = z(m+2:m+n+1,:);
```

Comment: This code is not runnable. Can you provide a runnable example? For example, you should provide `X`, etc.